# Send data (Job #) in one column to another spreadsheet, if another column contains data

Tags: excel

Here is a sample of the data I'm using. The letters are the estimated time in each area of the workshop (i.e. A. is clean up, B. is welding etc.):

```
   J/C #    A.  B.  C.  D.  E.  F.  G.  H.  TOTAL 
    97647   45  45      90  30  120         330
    97651   15          30                  45
    97626
    99999   60  120         75  360         615
    11111   90          30  15  15          150
    12345   10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  360
```

On another sheet I need a column of all the Job Card numbers (J/C #) for each workshop area. I would like these automatically to appear when the budgeted time is put into this first sheet.

For example the Welding Sheet will have the following J/C #.

```
97647
99999
12345
```

I have been trying INDEX and MATCH and LOOKUP and VLOOKUP functions, but haven't yet found a solution.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm unclear on where the cross-reference between A, B, C, etc and Cleanup, Welding, blah-blah, etc is kept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution that works -- hopefully I can explain it clearly.

Let's say your table is on "Sheet1".  Create new sheets, one for each workshop (so, I have a "Sheet1", "A","B","C",...,"H").

In your "A" sheet, put this formula in A1:
`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10000,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!B$2:B$10000<>"",ROW(Sheet1!A$2:A$10000)-ROW(Sheet1!A$2)+1),ROWS(Sheet1!A$2:A2))),"")`  Enter with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and drag down.

This will create a population of those Job #s that have some value under the "A." column in "Sheet1".

To use this formula for your "B." column, put this formula in sheet "B", cell A1:
`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10000,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!C$2:C$10000<>"",ROW(Sheet1!A$2:A$10000)-ROW(Sheet1!A$2)+1),ROWS(Sheet1!A$2:A2))),"")`

Notice the only change is in the "SMALL(IF(Sheet1!**C$2:C$10000**<>..."  That's because since you want to return any job numbers for your "B." column, which is in Column C of Sheet1.  ...so for your "C." Sheet, in A1, put the above formula but using column D for the "Small(If(Sheet1!**C$2:C$10000**" part.

Does this make sense?

The only thing is that you'll need to tweak depending on your sheet names (since I don't know what C,D,E, etc. actually refer to).

Comment: Sorry Ive been so Slow to thank you. Thank you It works :)

Comment: @luk - Hurray! Do you mind marking as "Answer" (click the check left of the post) if it worked for you? Thanks!